# Indexable signature not found in object literal in Flow

Tags: flowtype

I have this interface:

```
interface IFormData {
    [string]: string
};

export type { IFormData };
```

It's simple interface that accepts key-value only string. But when I use this,

```
const formData:IFormData = { email: '...', password: '...' };
```

it gives me this error:

> [flow] property `$key` of IFormData (Indexable signature not found in object literal)

I also tried this, but it gives me same error:

```
var formData: IFormData;    // Error
formData['email'] = ...;
formData['password'] = ...;
```

I searched this on google almost 2 days, but still stuck in here and I need some help!

Any advice will very appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you switch from `interface` to `type`, Flow seems to be a lot happier with this sort of thing:

```
type IFormData = {
    [string]: string
}

const formData: IFormData = { email: '...', password: '...' };
```

I'm guessing the fact that interfaces are nominally typed, rather than structurally typed, has something to do with this.

Comment: What does being "nominally typed, rather than structurally typed" mean?

Comment: The flow documentation has a [section on nominal vs. structural typing](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/nominal-structural/).